# How make a conditional property in a YML file in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I want to be able to have something like:

```
some-property: '#{${ENV_VAR_1:} == "someVal" ? boo + "someVal" : ${ENV_VAR_1}}'
```

Is something like this possible?

When I try this currently, I get the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operand must not be null
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.(SpelNodeImpl.java:77) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.(Ternary.java:40) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:183) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:131) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpressions(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:121) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseTemplate(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:62) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:49) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>       ... 51 common frames omitted

Comment: I think that you can find your answer at this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934213/conditional-check-in-yaml-file-to-show-the-proper-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934213/conditional-check-in-yaml-file-to-show-the-proper-content)

Comment: Found a beautiful solution without SpEL right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56321961/2032157

Answer (score 9):

you can also do like below using SPEL in YML -

```
some-property: '#{"${ENV_VAR_1:}".equals("someVal")?"boo" + "someVal":"${ENV_VAR_1:}"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use multi-profile instead of if/else. like this:

```
---
spring:
    profiles: VAR_1
some-property: boo
---
spring:
    profiles: VAR_2, VAR_3
some-property: foo
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `application.yaml` add an environment variable reference to your `spring.profiles.active`.

Then add profiles for each condition and a profile for the default case:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - ${ENV_VAR_1:default}


---
spring:
  profiles: default

some-property: defaultValue

---
spring:
  profiles: env1

some-property: env1Value

---
spring:
  profiles: env2

some-property: env2Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track; you're passing in a `SPEL` expression that looks like it's attempting to get evaluated.

It appears that one of the operands is `null` (hence the `Operand must not be null`).

You'll have to very this, but it looks like:

```
${ENV_VAR_1:}
```

Is evaluating to `null`. It is clearly parsing a ternary, which is part of your stacktrace, but one of those operands needs to have a value. I'd create a default for the `ENV_VAR`s, like `${ENV_VAR_1:default}` and see if the parsing works for you. Otherwise, check if `boo` is `null` and test with a static value for that.