# Spring conditional yaml property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml

That's how one line of my `.yaml` properties file looks like:

```
profiles.active: rabbit-${CLUSTER_ENV}, mongo-${CLUSTER_ENV} ...
```

I want to put the below logic only for `rabbit-` property:

```
if(CLUSTER_ENV == "local") {
   return "dev";
} else {
   return CLUSTER_ENV;
}
```

Other properties should be filled with `local` but only in this place the property value should be conditionally filled. Can I somehow add this logic in Spring yaml properties?

Comment: it is cleaner to have a yaml per profile, so if your active profile is dev, then spring-boot will load application-dev.yml (https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-profiles-1), what you can do in this case have explicit setting of CLUSTER_ENV (I am assuming it's an environment variable so that's easy to change)

Comment: I have a yaml per profile but I want to use a different profile just for Rabbit properties and that's why I need a conditional evaluation.

Comment: I guess then you might have to do it programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not look pretty, but you can use something like:

```
 #this can be added on startup
mykey: key1

#a map with your condition
mymap:
  key1: val1
  key2: val2

#your value based on the condition
conditional: con-${mymap.${mykey}}
```

regards,
WiPU

UPDATE based on comment:

```
 #this can be added on startup as variable
mykey: local

#a map with your condition
mymap:
  local: dev
  xyz: test

# your value based on the condition or the key as fallback if the key is not 
# present in mymap.
conditional: con-${mymap.${mykey}:${mykey}}
```

Comment: But this assumes that there are only two possible keys? In my case `CLUSTER_ENV` can have many different values and if there is no mapping for the value then the value itself should be returned.

Comment: you can add a fallback to your key if it is not present in the map like: `conditional: con-${mymap.${mykey}:${mykey}}`.