# How to Compare Value in application.yml

Tags: java, spring, yaml, flyway, spring-el

I want to enable flyway only if environment is dev for other environments it should be disabled. It can be define while creating a profile for each environment but there is only one profile.

I tried couple version of below script but I had string cast problem.

```
flyway:
    enabled: ${env} == 'dev'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845990/spring-use-one-application-properties-for-production-and-another-for-debug

Comment: Create an environment specific config which sets this to `true` and set the default to `false`.

Comment: @M.Deinum It is also an option but we need to change whole stack due to it is aws env. and requires ops team to it. I just wonder to perform without it

Comment: Why would you need the ops team? Just include a file into your application and you are done.

Comment: @M.Deinum permission lacks :) enterprise world

Comment: If you can create this what you have now you can create a file. That has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: @aksappy  `'#{"${env:}".equals("dev") ?  true : false"}' `  give error as string to boolean problem, but this is what I actually want to do.

Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to boolean

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112436/how-make-a-conditional-property-in-a-yml-file-in-spring-boot), the following SpEL in application.yaml does the trick.

Spring will automatically convert string representations of `true` and `false` to a `Boolean` while resolving properties.

```yaml
flyway.enabled: '#{ "${env:false}".equals("dev") ? "true" : "false" }'
```

Comment: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.flyway.enabled' to boolean:

```    Property: spring.flyway.enabled
    Value: '#{ "${env:false}".equals("dev") ? "true" : "false" }'
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:57:14
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to boolean
```

Comment: I have created a working example in [github](https://github.com/aksappy/spring-spel-demo). Let me know what is the difference from your project.

Comment: The difference is you havent used flyway library and there is no dependency that require this property as boolean